# How can i get the row selected in the DataGrid or GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagrid

Can i get the row selected in th GridView or DataGrid in ASP.NET? Please help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging (object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
}
```

Comment: Am not getting  this GridViewSelectEventArgs .

Comment: @programmer4programming: What?

Comment: @programmer4programming: Are you tapping into selectedindexchanging or selectedindexchanged event?  the changed event does not use GridVIewSelectEventArgs...